# How to get the arguments of a third-party process

Tags: go

There is a process, for example test.exe , it is launched with arguments --argument1 --argument2 and they are visible through the task manager.
Question: How do I get these arguments through golang?

[image: What i need to parse]

Comment: It's a mess. :-) On Linux, all it takes is to read a file from `/proc`. On Windows, you need to interact with a WMI object. For something in the .Net ecosystem it is reasonably easy, but in Go you will need to play with OLE/COM, somewhat like this: https://github.com/yusufpapurcu/wmi

Answer (score 1):

I found solution.

```
import (
"github.com/shirou/gopsutil/v3/process"
)

func main(){
processes, _ := process.Processes()
for _, process := range processes {
    cmd, _ := process.Cmdline()
    fmt.Println(cmd)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The program is actually launched with flags: `--arg1=value --arg2=anotherValue`

I'd rather suggest an idiomatic approach using Go's [`flag` package](https://pkg.go.dev/flag).

It's always better to avoid increasing complexity to your programs by adding external packages, specially when Go has something for your need.

[Here](https://gobyexample.com/command-line-flags) is a usage example.